# Consistent background for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've applied a semi-transparent image to my UITableViewCell.contentView. Whenever I add my custom accessoryView, it doesn't have the right background as shown here:

[image]

This is the relevant code:

```
UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
[tableViewCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-bg.png"]]];
//[tableViewCell.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-bg.png"]]];
tableViewCell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

UIButton *accessoryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[accessoryButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[accessoryButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34)];
tableViewCell.accessoryView = accessoryButton;
```

I've also tried adding the background image to `backgroundView` instead of `contentView`, but it doesn't show up at all. How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UITableViewCell crate one UIImage object. Add it on your cell. And then add all the other objects on the image. You'll get the desire screens that way.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
UIImageView *imgViewCell = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [imgViewCell setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 45.0f)];
        [imgViewCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list_bg"]];
        [imgViewCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cellView.contentView addSubview:imgViewCell];
        [imgViewCell release];  


             UILabel *nameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 2.0f, 200.0f, 40.0f)];

        [nameLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]];
             [nameLbl setText:@"Test"];  
        [nameLbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [nameLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cellView.contentView addSubview:nameLbl];



            UIButton *accessoryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [accessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [accessoryButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34)];
            cellView.accessoryView = accessoryButton;

Please use arrow.png background transparent
```